# Use MAC OS Library QTKit for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, macos, qtkit

Apple developer document has the [QTKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008155) examples. I have noticed that it is only for Mac OS X v10.4 and I don't see QTKit in frameworks list. Is there anyway I can use this framework in developing my iPhone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QTKIt wasn't ported to the iPhone. Depending on what you want to do (audio or video), there are other libraries and components you can use instead.

You might want to check out:
1. Media Player Framework
2. AVAudioPlayer
3. Movie Player.

I'm sure you'll find the equivalent functions in one of those.